# Script involving screen OCR and text overlay in videogames

Tags: python, overlay, ocr

I need a script that uses on-screen OCR to recognize some text on specific areas of the screen, and then based on that to display some other text on the screen as an overlay over a full-screen videogame.

The problem is that I have no idea where to start. I'm thinking of writing the script in Python, since it is the only language that I can rely on, but should it be simple enough I guess I could use other languages. Also, the overlay part is *optional*: should it be a tough problem I can send the overlay text to my smartphone instead.

I'm asking here so I can get some hints on where to get started from some experienced programmers.

Comment: Personally I've had success in similar use(without displaying overlay though) using pyscreenshot and pil/pillow for getting parts of game's display and using Google's Tesseract OCR via pytesseract for text and imagehash for specific static image recognition.

Comment: @MaciejM Getting `TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file ./tessdata/eng.traineddata')` when I try to run `print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('screenshot1.png' , lang='eng'))` in python console. Running tesseract alone in cmd works just fine. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @Merekth I'd guess it's something with your tesseract configuration or evironmental variables. Did you try running the script in tesseract directory? From this `./tessdata/eng.traineddata` I see it's using relative directory to tesseract folder. Not sure how exactly pytesseract is calling the tesseract itself and what's being used as working directory there. You may have better luck just making new question about that specific problem if you haven't figured it out already.

Comment: @MaciejM Running the script in tesseract directory works. So it seems to be a path related problem. Tesseract is already set as a environmental variable. I tried to edit pytesseract config in order to point it to the complete path, but I'm getting `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`. Script is ran in with admin privilege. Do you suggest making another question for this?